# CMake: OpenCV Headerfiles couldn't be found after generating a MS-VS-Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, header-files

I'm new to CMake and OpenCV and have some problems with a CMake generated Microsoft Visual Studio Project.

I'm aming at building a little video capture program that uses my webcam to record a little .avi video. This program should also work on my little Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (a Linux Distribution) installed and that's the point where I want to use CMake.

I've already created this program with Visual Studio and everything works fine.
But when I try to build it with CMake and want to compile the generated Visual Studio Project I get the following errors inside VS:

> Error C1083 File Cannot open include file: "opencv2/core.hpp": No such
>   file or directory VideoCapture    C:\Program
>   Files\opencv\sources\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp   46
>
> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: "opencv2/core.hpp": No such file
>   or directory  VideoCapture    C:\Program
>   Files\opencv\sources\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp   46
>
> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: "opencv2/core.hpp": No such file
>   or directory  VideoCapture    C:\Program
>   Files\opencv\sources\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp   46

This errors occur in the header file opencv.hpp which is part of OpenCV. From my point of view this errors shouldn't occur because I have properly added the include path to the build target in the CMakeLists.txt file.

content of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)  
project(VideoCapture)   

# change the following path if you change the environment  
SET(OPENCV_DIR "C:/Program Files/opencv")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("include" "${OPENCV_DIR}/sources/include")

add_executable(VideoCapture "src/VideoCapture.cpp" "src/VideoCaptureEx.cpp" "src/main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(VideoCapture "${OPENCV_DIR}/build/x64/vc14/bin/opencv_world310.dll")
```

the file tree:

```
/Project
    |---CMakeLists.txt
    |---build
    |---include
    |      |--- VideoCapture.h
    |      |--- VideoCaptureEx.h
    |
    |---src
         |---main.cpp
         |---VideoCapture.cpp
         |---VideoCaptureEx.cpp
```

In main.cpp I create an object from the class VideoCaptureEx which inherits from VideoCapture and in VideoCapture.h I include the needed openCV header:

```
#ifndef _VIDEOCAPTURE_H_
#define _VIDEOCAPTURE_H_

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
.
.
.
```

I have also tried to use the find_package(...) cmake command but it did not work because cmake was unable to find the configuration file.
However it should be also possible to do it this way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there an `opencv2` folder inside `C:/Program Files/opencv/sources/include`?

Comment: ***I have also tried to use the find_package(...) cmake command but it did not work because cmake was unable to find the configuration file.*** This is the correct way. Did you build opencv from source?

Comment: No I have used the official Installer for Windows. OpenCV was also installed correctly despite the fact that the configuration file could not be found by cmake (but this file exists). All include files and the dll exist to.

Comment: The include path should be  the `${OPENCV_DIR}/build/include`?